# Serialization List<T> issue

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I've faced with next serialization issue. I have a list of some `MyObject` class that I want to serialize,but cannot do it in the desired view. Problem is the following. I have this class structures:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
public class Response : List<MyObject> {}

[XmlElement("myObject")]
public class MyObject { ... }
```

and after the serialization I get this one:

```
<response>
    <myObject>
        ...
    </myObject>
    <myObject>
        ...
    </myObject>
    <myObject>
        ...
    </myObject>
</response>
```

but I need this one:

```
<response>
    <myObejcts>
        <myObject>
            ...
        </myObject>
        <myObject>
            ...
        </myObject>
        <myObject>
            ...
        </myObject>
    </myObejcts>
</response>
```

Can I in any way get desire XML structure without adding property

```
public List<MyObject> {get; set;}
```

to `Response` class. The reason why I cannot use `List` property is because I use Entity Framework and in this case EF ganarate some extra unwanted tables in database.

Comment: Is XmlElement valid on class level? What is stopping you from making an extra class that wraps the Response?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your full Response object, and then use this one to serialize?

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    [XmlArray("MyObjects")]
    [XmlArrayItem]
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public ResponseWrapper()
    {
    }

    public ResponseWrapper(List<T> items)
    {
        this.Items = items;
    }
}
```

which then generates an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http:
//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyObjects>
    <MyObject>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Buck</Name>
    </MyObject>
    <MyObject>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Rogers</Name>
    </MyObject>
    <MyObject>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Name>Flash</Name>
    </MyObject>
    <MyObject>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <Name>Gordon</Name>
    </MyObject>
  </MyObjects>
</response>
```

Just, it still requires you to do some extra work, yes :)

Answer (score -1):

@Vsevywniy Hello again, Though I still believe creating a Wrapper Class is the best approach to achieve this. Another Option can be Implementing IXmlSerializable to control the Serialization and add a custom element. I am able to serialize your class structure to your expected XML. Please have a look at the code below:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var products = new MyObjects()
            {
                new MyObject() {Id = 1, Name = "Dell"},
                new MyObject() {Id = 2, Name = "Sony"},
                new MyObject() {Id = 3, Name = "HP"}
            };

            var serializeObject = SerializeObject<MyObjects>(products);
            Console.WriteLine(serializeObject);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string SerializeObject<T>(Object data)
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                var xmlData = new MemoryStream();
                var xmlEncodedData = new XmlTextWriter(xmlData, Encoding.UTF8);
                var serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                serial.Serialize(xmlEncodedData, data);
                xmlData.Position = 0;

                var reader = new StreamReader(xmlData);

                result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Format("Error in return data");
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Response")]
    [Serializable]
    public class MyObjects : List<MyObject>, IXmlSerializable
    {

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("MyObjects");
            foreach (var myObject in this)
            {
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject)).Serialize(writer, myObject);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }


       }
}
```

Comment: There is EF generate extra Response table in the database, but I don't need it.

Comment: If this is EF Generated class, can't you change attribute of this class to XMLElement("MyObjects"). and then have another wrapper class with property of type Response.

Comment: It's not EF ganarated class actually is class used to ganarate table(code-first attempt). I have described that I don't use this scenario because it database hardfull scenario (extra stodage need).

Comment: @Vsevywniy Validation is not allowing me add my long code in comment, so I have edited my answer. Please go through the code.